# Fluid CSS layout breaks in firefox and IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

I want to position an image container next to a text box having the image always match the height of the text:

```
<-         50%        ->  <-         50%        ->         
+----------------------+  +----------------------+
| Lorem ipsum dolor si |  | some                 |
| t amet, consectetuer |  | image                |
| adipiscingelit. Aene |  |                      |
| an commodoligula ege |  |                      |
| t dolor.             |  |                      |
+----------------------+  +----------------------+
```

vs

```
+------------+  +------------+
| Lorem ipsu |  | some       |
| m dolor si |  | image      |
| t amet, co |  |            |
| nsectetuer |  |            |    Reduce
| adipiscing |  |            |<-- browser
| elit. Aene |  |            |    width
| an commodo |  |            |
| ligula ege |  |            |
| t dolor.   |  |            |
+------------+  +------------+
```

To achieve this I wrap both containers in a `div` and display the image as a background-image:

```
<div class="outerTable">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer</div>
    <div class="image">
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

with the following style:

```
.outerTable {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
.outerTable > div {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 2%;
    width: 50%;
}
.image {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.image > div {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/300/abstract/4);
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 6%;
    background-clip: content-box;
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

A working example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/KxFUL/

This works well in Chrome, Safari and Opera. But in FireFox the image covers the whole page and in IE11 the image is not shown at all…

Am I missing something – wrong concept altogether? Any ideas? Any different solutions?

Comment: Out of my own curiousity - why would you want an image be five times as high as it is wide?

Comment: Actually the real layout looks more like this: http://jsfiddle.net/hY9aH/1/ I just wanted to have a simple example to discuss…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is a slightly long winded one, but it's just changing the CSS really to achieve what I think you want.

So first I've tried to use padding instead of transparent borders, and the first padding I set was on the `.outer-table` itself.  Of course, that table is 100% width, so you'll need to add the box-sizing fix as suggested by Paul Irish:

`*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}`

Then, I set a padding right on the `.col-66` to create that even spacing (margin can't be used on `display: table-cell`).

The finally I set your background image on the `.image` rather than on an empty container inside that, which means no need for absolute positioning.

New CSS here:

```
/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-image: url(http://bradjasper.com/subtle-patterns-bookmarklet/patterns/concrete_wall.png);
    background-repeat: repeat repeat;
}
.outerTable {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    padding: 10px;
}
.outerTable > div {
    display: table-cell;
}
.col-33 {
    width: 33.333%
}
.col-66 {
    width: 66.666%;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.content {
    padding: 3.4%;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.content:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.image {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/300/abstract/4);
    background-size: cover;
    border: 10px white solid;
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

[**And a fiddle to finish it off.**](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/hY9aH/2/)

Comment: And if you didn't want to use `box-sixing` then you could just add another container to set the initial padding. http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/hY9aH/4/

Comment: Wow, this works in all major browsers and doesn't have the drawback of clipping the image like in Cams solution! But do we need `background-clip: padding-box;` in `.content`?

Comment: Oops! What if there isn't enough content in `.content`: http://jsfiddle.net/lucadou/hY9aH/5/ ???

Comment: I only can think of this really dirty hack: http://jsfiddle.net/lucadou/hY9aH/6/ But since I use media queries it might be okay to use it…

Comment: No you won't need the `background-clip` - good spot.  I didn't go through and remove all the unnecessary rules, I just added the fixes. Not sure I understand the second problem?  In your fiddle you've missed the `display: table` on the `.outerTable`. It looks ok if you use less text in the fiddle I gave? http://jsfiddle.net/lucadou/hY9aH/6/

Comment: You are right, I missed `display: Table` – http://jsfiddle.net/lucadou/hY9aH/9/ Thank you!

Comment: Looks like I put the wrong link in my comment.  Was late last night, sorry.  Glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you could do if you so desire.
Remove the  where you have a background image being set to. I get you are trying to tie that into the image having a border. But you can get that to work with a css drop shadow set to inset.

http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/KxFUL/4/

```
.outerTable > div {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 2%;
  width: 50%;
}
.image {
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/300/abstract/4);
}
```

Here is the code to add your border back as well

```
.image {
   background-color: #fff;
   background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/300/abstract/4);
   -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 13px #FFFFFF inset;
   box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 13px #ffffff;
 }
```

Update fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/KxFUL/6/

Comment: It's definitely a start! I'll give it a try … tomorrow…

Answer (score 0):

Table-cell elements aren't really meant to have `position: relative;` set on them (I believe it won't work if you try to set it on actual table cell `<td>`s, though I could be wrong).

Because you are using CSS tables, most of the modern browsers have allowed you to set it on them, but Firefox seems to be sticking to the idea of table-cells not allowing it.

You can get around this a few ways, but it will depend on what else you have going on.

For example, you can wrap an additional `<div>` around the content inside of the table-cell element, and then set it to be `position: relative;` instead. The downside of this is you will need to give it a set height, which won't work if you need the height to flow with content.

You could also do it with javascript/jQuery.

This article has a good run-down of that, so I won't bother explaining the process in detail, as he does it so much better:

http://css-tricks.com/absolutely-position-element-within-a-table-cell/

Note that he is using it on actual table elements, so you'll need to make some changes. Essentially, it's the same process as I listed above with the extra div, it just sets the height dynamically with the JS. You could adapt it to change the height on window resize to make it responsive, etc...

Lastly, (in terms of my suggestions, I'm sure there are more options not listed here) - and my preferred suggestion, you could use `display: inline-block;` to build your two-column layout, rather than `display: table-cell;`. This way would avoid the whole pitfall all-together, and will also cut down the amount of html elements you need to get the effect.

Here's a good read on that:

http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/

Comment: I really would like to avoid javascript solutions – but thanks for the info about `inline-block`! I'll check that out…

Comment: `float` would work as well, but it won't keep everything as neat, and could cause issues with other styles. But depending on your use-case, could be a valid option.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you set display:table-cell for .image div, then put inside it a absolute positioned element, table-cell can't contain absolute element, as the element in it takes the cordinates for positioning NOT from its parent (although its parent is relative), but from the table (or display:table)

Comment: Yes, I know – but maybe there is an other solution for my layout?

Comment: Well, at least in Chrome/Mac I can't see the image at all in your solution…

Answer (score 0):

You "can't" do absolute positioning in a table cell, in relation to the table cell (don't ask me why, I didn't invent this stupid CSS specification). In any case, .image should have position:relative for position:absolute to work.

I guess Chrome is nice and ignores standards, or something like that.

Comment: `.outerTable > div` equals `.image` in this case -> `position: relative`